# Database does not connect on Linux server after transfer

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I created a working web app with login/register etc using a local dev server/wamp on my laptop, but require to move it all to linux server on a different system. I recreated the database identically in phpMyadmin and i am using the following connection string:

```
   <?php
   $server = '150.204.20.22';
   $user = 'enramclo';
   $pass = '***';
   $dbname = 'enramclo';

   $dbcon = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbname)or die("Can not connect to Server.");
   ?>
```

All these details are correct, but it simply will now not connect. I have little experienc eof linux so is there something I need to know as to why it will not work?

Comment: Are you sure the server isn't localhost?

Comment: Any errors? Does the connection work? (e.g. through the `mysql` commandline client, Navicat, HeidiSQL, or what-have-you)

Comment: Does it work from the command line? Also, what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

What is the os type? You might have SELinux enabled. Try to execute in shell and see if it's works

```
setenforce Permissive
```